# GridView item animation not stopping

Tags: android, animation, android-gridview

I'm using animation on all items of `Gridview` by using `setLayoutAnimation(controller)` method but `cancel()` method for animation is not working .

My code is here:-

```
Animation   animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
AnimationSet  set = new AnimationSet(true);
set.addAnimation(animation);
LayoutAnimationController  controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set);
gridView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

I am unable to understand how to stop GridView Animation as no `start` method is called

Comment: What type of animation you put in gridview,I mean in particular gridview item or whole gridview???

Comment: particular gridview item

Comment: Do like this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/402be19aac627355dfe3b90b087b0594

Comment: yess ,but how could we cancel this animation.

Comment: have you try this animation.cancle(); ??

Comment: yes ,I have tried but it is not working.May be animation.cancel() is not working because here i am not using start animation.

Comment: Most probably animation are starting due to `setLayoutAnimation`

Comment: yes, but how can we stop animation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this one a try.This should probably work.

```
griddemo.clearAnimation();
griddemo.setLayoutAnimation(new LayoutAnimationController(new AnimationSet(false)));
((ImageAdapter)griddemo.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```